# PHP server (Apache) only compresses JSON output with ob_start

Tags: php, json, apache

So I’ve setup a web server for a REST API and I’m coding it in PHP.

I’ve set Apache so that I can use gzip compression:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType text/css .css
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Then using curl I test which headers I are sent back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 23:24:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Last-Modified: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 23:04:13 GMT
ETag: "b9413-522e1bf1eb540-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 4204
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Great, that seems to work. However, when I run my test script (index.php) which creates a resource and returns the object (or error) in a JSON response, I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 23:26:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.3
Location: api.domain.com/rest/v1/users/12345
Connection: close
Content-Language: en
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Why doesn’t the JSON response return compressed? I purposely return >700kb just to make sure it compresses something.

I explicitly set the `content-type` header in my server before returning a JSON response. Is this not enough? I’m guessing the fact that it’s a PHP file may be the problem but I’m not experienced with Apache enough to know if it would be a problem/the fix.

However, if I add `ob_start("ob_gzhandler”);` to my PHP code, the content is compressed.

Also, it’s worth mentioning the .txt and index.php are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try next (be sure `filter_module` is installed):

```
<IfModule filter_module>
     FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/json'"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is this instead of my current code? Or as well as?

Comment: It is an addition for the conf file.

Comment: I’m getting the server error: `FilterProvider takes three arguments, filter-name provider-name match-expression`

Comment: That compiled properly, but there’s still no compression unfortunately

Comment: One last try: don't use my change, instead add `application/x-httpd-php` after `application/json` in your original conf.